# fullscreen api not working on ios when using javascript

Tags: javascript

fullscreen api is not working in ios safari and chrome. I am trying to show a image in full screen but its not working in ios safari, could anyone help me on the same. Am i using the right property of document.

```
function getBrowserFullscreenElementProp() {
  if (typeof document.fullscreenElement !== "undefined") {
    return "fullscreenElement";
  } else if (typeof document.mozFullScreenElement !== "undefined") {
    return "mozFullScreenElement";
  } else if (typeof document.msFullscreenElement !== "undefined") {
    return "msFullscreenElement";
  } else if (typeof document.webkitFullscreenElement !== "undefined") {
    return "webkitFullscreenElement";
  } else {
    throw new Error("fullscreenElement is not supported by this browser");
  }
}
```

Tried

```
function getBrowserFullscreenElementProp() {
  if (typeof document.fullscreenElement !== "undefined") {
    return "fullscreenElement";
  } else if (typeof document.mozFullScreenElement !== "undefined") {
    return "mozFullScreenElement";
  } else if (typeof document.msFullscreenElement !== "undefined") {
    return "msFullscreenElement";
  } else if (typeof document.webkitCurrentFullScreenElement !== "undefined") {
    return "webkitCurrentFullScreenElement";
  } else {
    throw new Error("fullscreenElement is not supported by this browser");
  }
}
```

Comment: This code returns a string or throws an exception. What is your question?

Comment: it checks for a property webkitFullscreenElement but i am not able to get it in ios safari, it goes to exception since property is not found

Comment: I have updated the function, so the use case is i have an image when i click on the image i need to make the image to full screen mode its working in chrome but in ios phone getting exception

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Is there a way to tell whether Safari is fullscreen? (e.g. document.fullscreenElement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509389/is-there-a-way-to-tell-whether-safari-is-fullscreen-e-g-document-fullscreenel)

Comment: I have tried this still error exception

Comment: I can't see it in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232124/discussion-between-john-thomas-and-thomas-sablik).

Comment: I have added in the question, still same issue its going to exception

Comment: Any idea on this @ThomasSablik

Answer (score 4):

As per [can i use](https://caniuse.com/fullscreen): Safari for iPhone does not support the fullscreen API.

Comment: Is there any alternative ? or any solution because remaining for all its working

Comment: @ Quentin, any alternative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509389/is-there-a-way-to-tell-whether-safari-is-fullscreen-e-g-document-fullscreenel, here people has voted and accepted but i see for my case its not working any idea ?

Comment: @dev — That works just fine in Safari for macOS and Safari for iPadOS. There is no support for the fullscreen API for Safari for iOS.

Answer (score -2):

```
  if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
    document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  }
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: Does mot work on iOS as requested by the poster.