# full screen API not working on safari, ios

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

so, I use this code:

```
var toggleBtn = false;
function btnClick() {
  toggleBtn = !toggleBtn;
  document.getElementById("testText").innerHTML = toggleBtn;
  if (toggleBtn) {
    openfullscreen();
  }
  else {
    closefullscreen();
  }
}

function openfullscreen() {
    // Trigger fullscreen  
    if (document.getElementById("parent").requestFullscreen) {
      document.getElementById("parent").requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.getElementById("parent").mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
      document.getElementById("parent").mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.getElementById("parent").webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
      document.getElementById("parent").webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.getElementById("parent").webkitRequestFullScreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
      document.getElementById("parent").webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
  else if (document.getElementById("parent").msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
      document.getElementById("parent").msRequestFullscreen();
    }
  }

 function closefullscreen(){
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullScreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
      document.webkitExitFullScreen();
    }
   else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
```

and I have a problem on safari, iOS 15.5. it works, but not always. sometimes when I hit the button and change orientation to landscape full screen is working, sometimes it's not. maybe someone knows if it's possible to make full screen API work for safari, iPhone, as I'd does on android?

Comment: [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) is [not fully supported on Safari/iOS](https://caniuse.com/fullscreen). Did you happen do see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67451504/fullscreen-api-not-working-on-ios-when-using-javascript)?

Comment: Safari is continuing a tradition of not implementing widely supported features

Comment: @Konrad yeah, I got it. but isn't there any alternative to make a video / image full screen on iPhone safari? like at all?